# I can not use $.uniform.update(); dropdownlist in my project

Tags: jquery, select, uniform

I'm using jQuery Uniform on my site.
Some select are blocked, if I choose any one option in the first select, the second is automatically unlocked. The problem is that the uniform is not changing the appearance of the select that was released, visually it remains inactive.
See an example on the site: [www.cataplanos.com.br](http://www.cataplanos.com.br)
In "Incluir Dependentes?", select "Sim" > In "Dependente 1" select any value to enable the next select "Dependente 2".

My code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("select").uniform();
        });
    });
```

I tried to use this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("select").uniform();
        });

        $.uniform.update();
    });
```

Is this right?

Comment: No, it's not. You should call `$.uniform.update()` _after_ the action that changes the state of the wrapped controls (`select`, in your case). Please understand that `update` method is just a replacement for DOM Mutation event handling (as these are quite inconsistent).

Comment: What happens when you run the code..? can you tell us if it's right or not or if it gives you the expected results / outcome...?

Comment: Replace the `$.uniform.update();` with `$("select").change(function(){$.uniform.update();});`

Comment: Hey @Mathew, you've done your good deed today! This completely solved my problem! Thank you all for your contribution fast!

Answer (score 1):

Just update the needed element after the change is done.

From the [documentation](http://uniformjs.com/#docs):

```
$.uniform.update([elem/selector string]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        jQuery('.ClassName').uniform();
```